# How to reload part of main view after submit using ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm new to MVC. How can I refresh part of my main view after submit action  in one of my partial views. I'm trying to make adding comments. I didn't use ajax until now so any help is good. I want after I create new comment in PartialView "Create" that it appers in PartialView GetCommentsByTicket...I hope that this is enough explanation...

```
@model HelpDeskApp.Models.Ticket

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

@*<h2>Details</h2>*@



<div class="panel panel-green">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Ticket
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div>
            @*<h4>ticket</h4>
    <hr />*@
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TicketId)
            </dt>

            <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TicketId)
            </dd>

            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject)
            </dt>

            <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Subject)
            </dd>

            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </dt>

            <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
            </dd>

            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedDate)
            </dt>

            <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddedDate)
            </dd>

            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category1.Name)
            </dt>

            <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Category1.Name)
            </dd>

            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority1.Name)
            </dt>

            <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Priority1.Name)
            </dd>

            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status1.Name)
            </dt>

            <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Status1.Name)
            </dd>

            <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.FirstName)
            </dt>

            <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.FirstName)
            </dd>

            </dl>
        </div>
        <p>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.TicketId }) |*@
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </p>


        <div id="postcomments">
            <hr />
            <h4>Komentari</h4>
            @{ Html.RenderAction("CommentsByTicket", "Comments", new { ticketId = Model.TicketId });}
        </div>



        <div id="create comments">
            @{ Html.RenderAction("Create", "Comments", new { Ticket = Model.TicketId });}
        </div>
        </div>



</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
    Panel Footer
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you'll have to add a lot more detail about the problem and the code you've tried before we're able to help you.

Comment: Trisha thanks for tip